# Facebook account identification and app security

Tags: android, ios, facebook, security, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating an app that will use Facebook Login process on iOS and android.

The app will track the name of the user (retrieve from Facebook profile) and the massage they post to the server.

Assume Mr. A login into my app using Facebook Login. Then he post a message into my Parse database.

Can someone Login into my app using another username and password and then change the name and post into my database as Mr.A Name?

Can this happen? or there is a mechanism that will protect user from doing that?

Comment: if u change the access token it automatically converted the admin name'

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail. I'm very newbie. So is it possible for Mr.B to post into database with Mr. A name instead of their own name?

Comment: already u posted Mr.A now working fine,k , if u need to change the name Mr.B in the place of Mr.A u need to pass the access token in the place of where u pass the parameters just add it ,it automatically converted to the admin name Mr.A to Mr.B

Comment: My goal is to protect Mr.B from posting into my database with Mr.A name because he is not Mr.A, he is Mr.B so It need to be Mr.B, Can I do that? or Mr.B can edit his name?